# can't connect to elasticsearch or kibana running on remote Ubuntu server

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

Quite a beginner to Elasticsearch and Kibana. I followed the instructions on Docker Hub pages to install them on my Ubuntu 18.04 server. Below are the webpages that I referred to:
[Elasticsearch 7.0.3](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch)
[Kibana 7.0.3](https://hub.docker.com/_/kibana)

After successfully installing the docker images, I can see both containers running on my server:
[image: both containers running]
I can also get right results when curling locally:
[image: curl elasticsearch locally]
[image: curl kibana locally]

However, both curl commands showed 'Failed to connect to [my server ip : the port number]: Time out' error if I curled from another machine. Two reasons that I could think of:

1. Firewall
2. The server is not listening on the correct ports

So I checked both. Below are the results:
[image: firewall and ports info]
I could be wrong but everything looks good to me. Any ideas?

-Updates

I forgot to mention that I am able to ping my ubuntu server because if I type [my server ip address] in my browser, it will give me this 'welcome to nginx' page
[image]

Comment: Are you able to ping Ubuntu server from your remote machine?

Comment: @7_R3X Yes. Please see the updates. Thanks for reminding me of that!

Answer (score 1):

Edit your elasticsearch.yml/kibana.yml files and use 0.0.0.0 as network.host instead of localhost.

To use your curl command,replace localhost by the ip address.

Comment: I didn't see the result of your docker ps. you need just to use a curl with the ip address of your ubuntu on the remote server instead of localhost